# Reflecting on Windows.UI.Xaml.TriggerCollection doesn't return correct methods details

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-runtime

I am trying to reflect on the Windows.UI.Xaml.TriggerCollection classes.  However, when I do the following:

```
typeof(Windows.UI.Xaml.TriggerCollection).GetMethods()
```

I do not get the methods detailed on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.triggercollection#methods).  I can then do:

```
typeof(Windows.UI.Xaml.TriggerCollection).GetTypeInfo().GetRuntimeMethods()
```

Which will return the correct method names, however, not the rest of their info.  All the methods appear to be private methods, even those which should be public as detailed on msdn.  The same goes for .DeclaredMethods, where the methods all appear to be private, even those which should be public.

How do you retrieve the underline method and property info for winrt types?  Or for a specific case, cow can do you get all the methods under TriggerCollection with their correct method info?

Comment: What methods do you get?

Comment: I see, I need to use GetRuntimeMethods on the GetTypeInfo to retrieve the methods.  However, they all show up as private.  Will expand my question.